# "Internal Server Error" Dreamweaver cc 2018

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I am creating a form in html, on Dreamweaver cc 2018. For my new website. But every time I use it ,it prints "Internal Server Error". Which means that there is a problem, but no matter how many websites I look for answers on there it never works. Here is my form code.

```
<form action="myemail@exemple.com" method="get" enctype="text/plain">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

I have tried "get" "post" and "default"
And I am not on a server.

Thanks :-)

Comment: When does this error emits? When you submitting the form? Or when you're loading it?

Comment: When submitting the form, but I just added that the website isn't on a server, and that might be the problem .

Comment: Ah... I am using it through my computer without a current domain name, just going through dreamweaver, so if i put it on MAMP should it then work?

Comment: Your `action` is invalid. If you want to send an email when the form is submitted, you would need to do this on the server-side end (ie via PHP script) - like so: `action="submit-form.php"`. The script will have to do all validation and the email sending part.

Comment: @anwenhtml you don't necessarily need a domain name to send emails, you could even use Gmail or Hotmail SMTP (email) servers to send emails for you. It is just a matter of configuring it all correctly.

Comment: @ Max Maxymenko  - action doesn't have to refer to a file. You can email straight from a form.

Comment: @Roysh you can set the action field of the form as ‘mailto’. In this case, the web browser *might* invokes the email client to send the form submission to the email address specified. Here is more: http://form.guide/email-form/html-email-form.html

Comment: @Roysh thanks for the link just skimmed through it and will to more research in a minute, but I understand now why it isn't working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to send a mail you'll need to use `action="mailto:myemail@exemple.com"` instead of `action="myemail@exemple.com"`